# Web-To-Case person response

Tags: web-to-case

Is there a way to include the initial message sent via the Web-To-Case to appear as either an email on the case or any way that you can include the original message in the first response email from a person ( not the auto-response rule)

e.g. Case comes in, Auto response pings out from no reply mail ( no record created on case level), User wants to reply - Has to manually copy&paste original message, before using a template or a message is written themselves.

Comment: i think you could achieve this using process builder, case come is, if the origin = web to case -> create a new record of type email message where the parent ID is your case. Then your users could reply and the initial customer message is already included

Comment: Thank you, I will test this out tomorrow!